# Google Tag Manager - custom Templates - injectScript API never seems to run

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have been trying my hands on creating a custom template tag, like so:

### Code

```js
// Require the necessary APIs
const logToConsole = require('logToConsole');
const injectScript = require('injectScript');

// construct URL
const url = "https://www.dwin1.com/" + data.merchantId + '.js';

// If the user chose to log debug output, initialize the logging method
const log = data.debug ? logToConsole : (() => {});

log('AWIN: Loading script from ' + url);

// If the script loaded successfully, log a message and signal success
const onSuccess = () => {
  log('AWIN: Script loaded successfully.');
  data.gtmOnSuccess();
};

// If the script fails to load, log a message and signal failure
const onFailure = () => {
  log('AWIN: Script load failed.');
  data.gtmOnFailure();
};


injectScript(url, onSuccess, onFailure, url);
```

### Permissions

URL Pattern match: `https://www.dwin1.com/`

### Tests

but when I now try to run a test like so

```js
const mockData = {
  merchantId: 1001,
  debug: true
};

// Call runCode to run the template's code.
runCode(mockData);

// Verify that the tag finished successfully.
assertApi('gtmOnSuccess').wasCalled();
```

I get this gnarly error and don't know why:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hey even I faced the same issue, but as I debugged it was due to `AdBlocker` which was blocking the script, you need to allow it and check if you have any `AdBlocker` installed on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this gtmOnSuccess() function has to be called in your template code, not in your DOM after injection.

In example, if you add this line of code by the end of your code :

```
injectScript(url, onSuccess, onFailure, url);
data.gtmOnSuccess();
```

Your test will be successful

Hope this helps